# My Mac is constantly fetching 2MB/s from the network

Tags: network, macos

We got our company macs, and I installed iStat menus on mine. What caught my eye is that there is a constant network traffic, ~2MB/s. Activity monitor also reports the same:

[image: activity monitor]

However, the process list doesn't show anything excessive:

[image: list of processes]

The process with the most frequent change of rcvd packets is netbiosd, however it's received bytes show really small amounts.

Each Mac is a member of AD domain, and we all have Kaspersky running (I removed mine, but the traffic still remains).

After adding Little Snitch and enabling Show Local Network in it, I don't see excessive traffic in Little Snitch. It shows something like 0.2-1.5kB/s, which is what I would expect.

Any ideas what is happening here? Is there really 2MB/s traffic going in the machine, or is this a bug in Sierra?

Comment: Do you back up time machine to a network drive such as a Time Capsule or NAS?

Comment: No, there is no Time Capsule, not NAS. Machine mounts two CIFS volumes, but the traffic remains even after I unmount them.

Comment: So, what is happening is that there are ~2k multicast requests hitting the machine. That's why there is no process that's receiving it. Still find it buggy that it shows up on Activity monitor.